# can't view logcat tool window in Android Studio 3.2.1 on MacOS

Tags: android-studio, adb, logcat, android-studio-3.0

I created a new dummy Kotlin project in Android Studio. I'm not developing an app, I just need it as a toolset to test apps on emulators and devices. For some reason Logcat window is not available in View > Tool Windows.

[image]

I have a device connected. Shell command `adb logcat` works fine from Studio's terminal.

I looked in preferences, tried updating platform tools, didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try the shortcut `cmd + 6`

Comment: tried, doesn't help. Tool Windows doesn't show this shortcut either

Comment: The same on Windows 7.